# How can I add a picklist to a case form for custom entities (note: replace the normal lookup field)?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have a requirement that a custom entity 'Priority' is selected on the case form but rather than using the normal lookup method, I want to display a picklist with the priority entitys listed.

One solution I have come up with is to have the lookup field on the form as normal but not set to visible and have a jscript routine add a select to the DOM looking up the required values at using a JSON request. On the selected changed event of the custom select, I can programatically set the value of the lookup.

The problem with this is it's quite messy and not supported.

Is there is a supported way to do what I want and if not, can anyone see any issues with the solution provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings the value of a lookup with javascript is supported. Custom html controls are suported as web resources. Your solution will work and actually is a supported customization.

As for your other options...

Presumably this request stems from the users thinking it takes "too many clicks and too much time" to select from such a short list of Priority entities. Is it possible your requirements are negotiable? Are your users aware of all two nice features of the lookup: 1. you can type the first few letters of the Priority's name and tab out, and it will auto-complete for you. 2. Similarily you can type just the first couple letters and a dropdown will expand below the lookup with the available options. Its quite fast and you dont need to load a seperate screen which I am assuming is their usability concern.

Alternatively, if they are dead-set on the dropdown, can this Priority data be represented as an optionset? I'm a bit suprised that you needed an entity for Priority concerns, what metadata about priority do you need?

Comment: The reason for the entity is I need to store details such as minutes to respond and minutes to resolve. These fields will later be used for SLA reporting.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Any luck finding out if the users will "settle" for the lookup?

Comment: They will 'settle' for whatever they get. Making the process as slick as possible eases the cogs. Since the will only ever be a handful of options to select from, the lookup is way overkill. I'm going to handle it in the way we have described above, web resource hooks into the form and set the value of the required lookup in the onchange event.